# SharePoint 2013 REST query not filtering properly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I have a query that I want to filter on by AuthorID

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('News Item Preferences')/items?$select=Id,PreferredChannels/Title,MaxItems&$filter=AppID eq '29235c13-0c36-472d-a5c6-ce4a584089db' and Author eq 3417&$expand=PreferredChannels/Title
```

but this does not work.

But this does (if I remove the filter for author)

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('News Item Preferences')/items?$select=Id,PreferredChannels/Title,MaxItems&$filter=AppID eq '29235c13-0c36-472d-a5c6-ce4a584089db'&$expand=PreferredChannels/Title
```

Also this works too

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('News Item Preferences')/items?filter=(Author eq 3417)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? Why can I not combine the Author filter?

Thanks

Comment: Is AuthorID refinable in the Search Schema?

Answer (score 0):

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('News Item Preferences')/items?filter=(Author eq 3417)
```

It works but it's doing nothing in your query (It should return all items). You need to write `$filter` not `filter`.  Another thing it should be `AuthorId` instead of `Author`. So try following

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('News Item Preferences')/items?$select=Id,PreferredChannels/Title,MaxItems&$filter=(AppID eq '29235c13-0c36-472d-a5c6-ce4a584089db') and (AuthorId eq 3417)&$expand=PreferredChannels
```

Or use

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('News Item Preferences')/items?$select=Id,PreferredChannels/Title,MaxIt‌​ems,Author/Id&$filte‌​r=(AppID eq '29235c13-0c36-472d-a5c6-ce4a584089db') and (Author/Id eq 3417)&$expand=PreferredChannels,Author
```

**PS:** I am assuming that you mean Created By column by `Author`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45327/discussion-on-answer-by-atish-dipongkor-sharepoint-2013-rest-query-not-filtering).

Comment: What about my last update?

Comment: `The expression "Id,PreferredChannels/Title,MaxIt‌​ems,Author/Id" is not valid.`

Comment: Did you use `$expand=PreferredChannels,Author` perfectly? In my SP 2013 it works.